# Schedule a python script loading data to BigQuery under windows 10

Tags: python, windows, oauth, google-bigquery

Is there a way to schedule a python script loading data to Bigquery without having to copy the authentication code generated from a google account link for each run.

I am currently using the windows task scheduler to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the credentials by following this link cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts.

In the python script, you can pass the json file path directly to the function you are using to read/write from/to BQ with the `private_key` argument.

`pandas_gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id= myprojectid, ..., private_key= 'jsonfilepath', dialect=’legacy’)`

`pandas.to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize=10000, ..., private_key='jsonfilepath')`

Then you schedule the task to run the python script as you'll normally do with the windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You'll have to use [service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts). After you create one, download it to your local as a JSON file and use it in your Python script, something like:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery as bq
client =  bq.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/credentials.json')
```

This will make all the connections to BigQuery you need with authentication already handled automatically for you.

Comment: looks like your message was cut before posting

Comment: I created the  credentials through this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts.                                                   
I  can load data to BigQuery using cmd, but when using the task scheduler with the same commands my code never ends.                                                                                                             
I am building a machine learning classifier using for 4 computer nodes.

Comment: I dont quite understand. Are you able to connect to gcp using the service account?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect without having to enter the oauth code and I can read and write date from and to GBQ if I run my script from the command prompt (cmd terminal). But when I schedule the same task with the "task scheduler" the code never ends it appears with the mention "running" on the "task scheduler". On cmd it lasts for 20 mins only.